# iPad Flash replacement best practices

Tags: javascript, flash, ipad

I have a website that has a Flash banner.

For devices that do not support Flash (like iPads) I want to display an image instead.

What is the best practice to deal with this situation?

- Should this be handled from the front-end with JavaScript?
- Should this rather be handled from the back-end? (I am using Java on the back-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **swfobject**: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

It allows you to detect flash and if not present (or with a lower version than the one you exported your flash file) it will show an alternate content.

That's where you can place your "iPad" content. It can be images, or straightforward html, it's content.

BTW, the server-side (back-office) won't help you with identifying flash support, at least not at the first "visit", but you could use a cookie scheme and even with that you wouldn't have it at the first visit, so you need javascript at the front-end.

Comment: Not that it matters much but for the record, SWFObject is not from Adobe (as in "Adobe's swfobject").

Comment: @Lars You're right! Shamefully I didn't know that. I just corrected it.